# Failing a test after teardown_method has executed in pytest

Tags: python, plugins, pytest

I am trying to figure out how to write a pytest plugin that can be used to fail a test after it has been run (for anyone who wants more context, this is related to [astropy/pytest-openfiles#28](https://github.com/astropy/pytest-openfiles/pull/28)). Let's consider the following simple test file:

```
class TestClass:

    def setup_method(self, method):
        print("In setup_method")

    def teardown_method(self, method):
        print("In teardown_method")

    def test_simple(self):
        print("In test")
```

I can now define a `conftest.py` file that contains:

```
def pytest_runtest_teardown(item, nextitem):
    print("In pytest_runtest_teardown")
```

In this hook, I can carry out checks - for example in the case I'm interested in, we are checking for unclosed file handles. However, the issue is that this hook gets run after `setup_method` and after the test itself (`test_simple`) but before `teardown_method`:

```
% pytest test.py -vs
...
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                      

test.py::TestClass::test_simple In setup_method
In test
PASSEDIn pytest_runtest_teardown
In teardown_method
```

I have considered instead using:

```
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):

    if call.when != 'teardown':
        return

    print("In pytest_runtest_makereport")
```

which does get executed after `teardown_method` but at that point if I raise an exception pytest will output an `INTERNALERROR` and will still consider the test as successful.

Is there any way to fail/error a test after `teardown_method` has been called?

Answer (score 0):

After `test_simple` is over Pytest consider it done, everything from now own will be outside the test scope. You could add `@pytest.fixture` annotation to a function, this will provide you with `pytest` setup and teardown functionality. The test itself will be considered ass passed, but not the all suite. `TestClass` will be marked as failure with the exception raised from `teardown_method`

```
class TestClass:

    @pytest.fixture
    def run_for_test(self):
        self.setup_method()
        yield
        self.teardown_method()

    def setup_method(self, method):
        print("In setup_method")

    def teardown_method(self, method):
        print("In teardown_method")
        # just for the example
        if not method:
            raise AssertionError

    def test_simple(self):
        print("In test")
```

Output

```
In setup_method
.In test
In teardown_method
>           raise AssertionError
E           AssertionError
```